# Is there any book on statistical distributions?

Tags: distributions

I am a civil engineering student and my research area is traffic engineering. I have encountered different types of statistical distributions e.g. Poisson, binomial, Gumbel, Gaussian, Pearson type III, etc in traffic engineering literature. I understand some of the distributions and what kind of data they fit. But there are many distributions (e.g. Pearson distributions, Gumbel distribution, etc.) which are completely alien to me: I can't find a thorough explanation online or in any book which I could understand and apply in my research. Is there any book or online resource covering all statistical distributions with their applications?